# convert yaml to environment variable by selecting a KEY

Tags: bash, shell

I have a config file:

```
name: test
configmap:
  foo1: bar1
  foo2: bar2
secrets:
  secrets1: value1
```

whatever comes under `configmap` should be converted to ENV Variables. Like in above example, only 2 values will be converted to ENV variables:

```
export foo1=bar1
export foo2=bar2
```

I followed this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/539009/export-environment-variables-parsed-from-yaml-text-file
but could not get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a tool like [yq](/questions/tagged/yq) to create an output like:

```
key1=value1 key2=value2
```

Passing that to [`export`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/export.1p.html) will create the env vars.

---

```bash
export $(yq e '.configmap | to_entries | map(.key + "=" + .value) | join(" ")' input)
```

Local shell example, were your input is stored in a file called `input`:

```
$ echo $foo1 $foo2

$
$ export $(yq e '.configmap | to_entries | map(.key + "=" + .value) | join(" ")' input)
$
$ echo $foo1 $foo2
bar1 bar2
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

While I would recommend using a proper YAML parser as in the answer by @OstoneO, you could use awk to accomplish this task:

```
$ unset foo1; unset foo2 
$ export $(awk -F": " '/configmap:/{f=1} {if(f && NF==2) {printf "export %s=%s ", $1, $2}} /secrets:/{f=0}' test.yaml); 
$ echo $foo1 $foo2
bar1 bar2
```